# Enter PEM pass phrase when converting PKCS#12 certificate into PEM

Tags: openssl, command, pem, pkcs#12

I am using OpenSSL to convert my "me.p12" to PEM. When I generate "me.p12", I set a password for it. The "me.p12" contains a private key and a certificate.

When I convert it to PEM, I run command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in me.p12 -out me.pem
```

Then, it asked me for `Import Password`:

```
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
```

I entered the password I set to "me.p12", it was verified OK. But next, it ask me:

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

I have no idea what is that? When I generate "me.p12" I haven't set any other password. So, what is that? How to figure this out?

Answer (score 79):

"Enter PEM pass phrase" because openssl doesn't want to output private key in clear text. The password is used to output encrypted private key

Below command can be used to output private key in clear text. No password is then asked.

```
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in me.p12 -out me.pem
```

Comment: In fact, `-nodes` stands for **No DES**, meaning OpenSSL won't encrypt the output (with _3DES-CBC_)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I think this is the right answer:

```bsh
openssl pkcs12 \
  -passin pass:'your_pass' \ # Input file or pass phrase source
  -nodes \ # Don't encrypt private keys
  -in me.p12 \ # Input filename
  -out me.pem # Output filename
```

Usually you use it when writing a script it can be combined with:

```bsh
openssl genrsa \
  -passout pass:'your_pass' \ # Output file or pass phrase source
  -out ca.key \
  -des3 2048
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same case when this pass phrase appears for the first time, then you must install it, then later when the phrase appears again in the terminal, then you enter the pass phrase that you entered earlier.